# Dynamically add data in DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I need to create extention for  dynamically adding data to a dataTable in C#.

I write this code but it has a problem:

```
public static class ModelConverterToTVP
{
    public static SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter AsTableValuedParameter<T> (this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string typeName)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        // find properties
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        PropertyInfo[] readableProperties = properties.Where(w => w.CanRead).ToArray();

        var columnNames = (readableProperties.Select(s => s.Name)).ToArray();

        foreach (string name in columnNames)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(name, readableProperties.Single(s => s.Name.Equals(name)).PropertyType);
        }

        foreach (T obj in enumerable)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(
                columnNames.Select(s => readableProperties.Single
                    (s2 => s2.Name.Equals(s)).GetValue(obj))
                    .ToArray());
        }

        return dataTable.AsTableValuedParameter(typeName);
    }
}
```

and I pass to this extension this model :

```
public class AccessLevel
{
        public AccessLevel()
        {
            IsDelete = false;
        }

        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string Access { get; set; }
        public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
}
```

But when I need to return the `dataTable` , it was empty `{}` .

I put a breakpoint to find the problem :

properties =>

```
+       [0] {Int32 RoleId}  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo}
+       [1] {System.String Access}  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo}
+       [2] {Boolean IsDelete}  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo}
```

readableProperties =>

```
+       [0] {Int32 RoleId}  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo}
+       [1] {System.String Access}  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo}
+       [2] {Boolean IsDelete}  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo}
```

Now what's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am assuming that the extension method `AsTableValuedParameter(...)` should return `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked dataTable.Columns.Count and dataTable.Rows.Count ?
You haven't named your dataTable, so it looks like empty

```
public static class ModelConverterToTVP
{
public static SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter AsTableValuedParameter<T> (this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string typeName)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable(typeName);

        ...
    }
}
```